# Ionic 2 - InAppBrowser Insert CSS by File not Working

Tags: css, cordova, angular, ionic2, inappbrowser

Good afternoon,
I'm making an InAppBrowser in my app and i want to add CSS to it by a file in the project. So, I made this code:

```
let browser = new InAppBrowser('http://usefashion.com/', '_blank', 'location=no, zoom=no');
browser.on('loadstart').subscribe((e)=>{
    console.log('Carregando nova página.');
    SpinnerDialog.show('Carregando');
});
browser.on('loadstop').subscribe((e)=>{
    console.log('Página carregada.');
    SpinnerDialog.hide();
    browser.insertCss({
      file: 'assets/portalstyles.css'
    }).then((e)=>{ console.log('CSS adicionado.'); }).catch((e)=>{ console.log('Erro ao adicionar CSS. '+e); });
});
```

Although, the file are't added to page and in console I'm getting this message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

Can somebody help me?

Thks, Lucas.

Comment: Not really since the `TypeError` suggests that a property `apply` is called where in your code you show none

Comment: This is shown when I fire the `browser.insertCss()` (that is fired after the page load). I tried using `code` instead of `file` but it's not working: same error.